# What are some ways to implement this layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout, sectionedrecyclerviewadapter

I have a GridLayout using RecyclerView. I need to have an interface that looks like this -

[image]

Some items from the recycler view need to be displayed inside a container with rounded corners. What are some ways to implement this other than having a nested recycler view inside a recycler view section?

Comment: does container only contains even number of items?? Also will you be changing the number of items in the container?

Comment: No it can contain even or odd number of items. And the number of items will change, yes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use item decorators to achieve this, You will have to add some logic while drawing the container, for example to achieve the above picture, you will have to divide this container into four parts and draw top left for item 0, then top right for item 1, bottom left for item 2, and bottom right for item 3

If you can afford losing rounded corners then it would be really easy for you

Comment: Yeah I was trying to avoid doing this and have some more generic logic but I guess there is no easy way to do this :(

Comment: I dont think there is any other way. I can help you shape up the logic if you post some code